# How to show each user their running total of a custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'll start by throwing myself on the mercy of you fine people as a complete newb to php and stackoverflow. I've searched for the answer here and elsewhere and I'm having trouble piecing it all together.

Here's my problem- 
I've set up a form (using gravity forms) where logged in users can log "flight hours" after every flight. I'm using gravity forms to post this data to a custom post called "my-flight-record" where I've mapped all the fields from the form. Now, I simply want to show the user a running total of one field, wpcf-total-flight-time, but i only want to show the user their own total time.

Here's the code i'm currently using, but it sums ALL entries. I only want to sum the entry for the current user (who should also be logged in before they can even see this page).

```
<?php
//get current user
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $userPosts = get_posts(array('author' => $current_user->ID,      'post_type'=> 'my-flight-record')); 
        // loop to create array of ids by user
        foreach ($userPosts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $ids[] = get_the_ID();
        }
        $idList = implode(",", $ids);

        $meta_key = 'wpcf-total-flight-time';//set this to your custom field meta key
        $allflighthours = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
                                          SELECT meta_value
                                          FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                                          WHERE meta_key = %s
                                          AND post_id in (" . $idList . ")", $meta_key));
        echo 'My total flight hours logged = ' . array_sum( $allflighthours) . '';  ?>
```

This code results in a total, but for everyone, not just logged in user. Also, the '$idList = implode(",", $ids);' line results in an error for me.

Please help me help myself! I'm sure I've left out vital info - let me know what i'm missing!

Comment: If you want only to show for people who are online then you need to have a column that indicates whether they're logged on or not. select ... from ... where logged_in = 1 or something like that. If you simply want to check for a single user then it should be rather easy: select ... from ... where user_id = id. Can you clarify?

Comment: I really just need to check for the current user - only logged in users can access this info, so i don't believe i also need to check for logged in user here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need two separate database queries? Try this:

```
<?php
//get current user
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $userPosts = get_posts(array('author' => $current_user->ID,      
                                     'post_type'=> 'my-flight-record'));
        //initialize an empty array
        $flight_hours = array();
        // loop to create array of ids by user
        foreach ($userPosts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $flight_hours[] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-total-flight-time', true);
        }
        printf('My total flight hours logged = %s ', array_sum( $flight_hours) ); ?>
```

As ipauler notes in his answer, you should implement some error checking to make sure there is a logged in user, and the `wpcf-total-flight-time` data is both present and valid.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! This worked perfectly, and helped me understand what i was trying to do a little better!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if user is logged in 
Some example from wordpress documentation

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
         //no user logged in
      }
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo#Parameters

```
//get current user
        global $current_user;
if(is_user_logged_in()) {     
   get_currentuserinfo();

        $userPosts = get_posts(array('author' => $current_user->ID,      'post_type'=> 'my-flight-record')); 
        // loop to create array of ids by user
        foreach ($userPosts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $ids[] = get_the_ID();
        }
        $idList = implode(",", $ids);

        $meta_key = 'wpcf-total-flight-time';//set this to your custom field meta key
        $allflighthours = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
                                          SELECT meta_value
                                          FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                                          WHERE meta_key = %s
                                          AND post_id in (" . $idList . ")", $meta_key));
        echo 'My total flight hours logged = ' . array_sum( $allflighthours) . ''; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference - I'll research

Comment: Thanks again - this and the next post really helped me figure out what the heck I was trying to do!